# /usr/sbin/amavisd-new - why is pcmd/regex not working for this command in csf.pignore?

Tags: regex, amavis, csf, ubuntu-16.04, lfd

For some reason I cannot get CSF's LFD (/etc/csf/csf.pignore) to ignore `amavisd-new` running via perl. The daemon runs via `/usr/bin/perl /usr/sbin/amavisd-new (some mode)` however it seems that when I use regex based `pcmd:`, LFD won't ignore it. Is there something up with LFD and/or the regex used with `pcmd:` that I am not understanding? The other stuff I have used with `pcmd:` has worked fine. I do not want to ignore the amavis user, nor ignore perl. I am reloading changes with `csf -ra`.

Various ways I have tried:

```
pcmd:/usr/bin/perl\s/usr/sbin/amavisd-new.*
pcmd:.*/usr/bin/perl\s/usr/sbin/amavisd-new.*
pcmd:/usr/bin/perl.*/usr/sbin/amavisd-new.*
pcmd:.*/usr/bin/perl.*/usr/sbin/amavisd-new.*
pcmd:.*\s/usr/sbin/amavisd-new\s.*
pcmd:.*/usr/sbin/amavisd-new.*
pcmd:.*/usr/sbin/amavis.*
```

CSF: v9.24 (generic) on Ubuntu 16.04.1 - x86_64

```
Executable: /usr/bin/perl
Command Line (often faked in exploits): /usr/sbin/amavisd-new (master)
Command Line (often faked in exploits): /usr/sbin/amavisd-new (virgin child)
Command Line (often faked in exploits): /usr/sbin/amavisd-new (ch3-avail)
Command Line (often faked in exploits): /usr/sbin/amavisd-new (ch4-avail)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use regexp. Just do

```
exe:/usr/sbin/amavisd-new
```

in csf.pignore and see what happens. According to their forums this is the way to go for perl daemons. They're admitting it's unclear, since their lfd alarm speaks of a different executable (i.e. perl).

Comment: The OP is asking to use a regex.  Is there a bug or something that prevents that from working?

Comment: The OP asked why pcmd/regex was not letting him ignore CSF/LFD alerts for amavisd. I suffered from the exact same thing. Either way, this is more a question that needs to be asked at the Configserver Security & Firewall forum, since it's a software dev specific bug; https://forum.configserver.com/

Comment: If somebody gets a chance to link to the specific bug that'd be nice.  @julius: I deleted / hereby withdraw my review comment.  Thanks for the additional info.

Comment: I didn't realize it was a bug -- figured it was syntax or something. It's been awhile so I'm not sure what I tried in the past, but `exe:` and `pexe:` both fail. I didn't see anything about this bug on their forums, although 2 other posts speak of the same issue ignoring stuff that runs under perl.

Comment: any updates on this?
would be good to make use of regex on csf.pignore for processes that doesn't fully describe the command line

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons if CSF's LFD doesn't ignore your processes. [This blog article](https://return2.net/csf-lfd-firewall-csf-pigignore-not-working/) mentions a lot of factors and solutions.

To sum up:

1. Restart both CSF and LFD, not only CSF (`sudo service lfd restart`)
2. Don't use inline comments (looks good in your case)
3. Check RegEx syntax (also looks good in your case)
4. Check your system and side effects (logs, updates, file formatting, ...)